# HTTP tunnel to AWS S3 website through VPC ends in redirect error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-hosting, ssh-tunnel

I have a deployed an S3 website that is only accessible through a VPC.

I want to be able to tunnel my HTTP traffic through an EC2 instance in that VPC to access the website through a browser on my local machine.

- I have confirmed that public access to the bucket is off
- I have an S3 gateway endpoint in the VPC and confirmed that is routable in my subnets
- I have confirmed that I can retrieve objects from the bucket by using curl on the S3 website endpoint from an instance in the VPC

  - `curl {bucketname}.s3-website-{region}.amazonaws.com` -> retrieves index.html
- I start the ssh tunnel by forwarding target instance port 80 to port 3000 on my local machine

  - `ssh -v -N -L 3000:{bucketname}.s3-website-{region}.amazonaws.com:80 -i {keypair}.pem ec2-user@{ec2-instance-in-vpc}`
- I go to `localhost:3000` on my local machine to access the s3 site forwarded to that port, but instead I get redirected to the AWS S3 homepage https://aws.amazon.com/s3/ every time.

  - I get the following log message on the tunnel confirming that it accepted the forward request:
  - `debug1: Connection to port 3000 forwarding to {bucketname}.s3-website-{region}.amazonaws.com port 80 requested`
- I run `curl localhost:3000` on my local machine, and got the following redirect response

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1>
<ul>
<li>Code: WebsiteRedirect</li>
<li>Message: Request does not contain a bucket name.</li>
<li>RequestId: SDNB2B78GWJRQKY5</li>
<li>HostId: 6fxE5CUCdq+7fjZiOgIKzgKNfcsi84g+XDWArAcjzrIDly+VPsF69bT3EWOQgXlxIgroS/Brq5w=</li>
</ul>
<hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

Has anyone encountered this error before?  Is there a better way to test connectivity of a private S3 website?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a deployed an S3 website that is only accessible through a VPC.

There is **no such thing**. So that's why it does not work. S3 websites can only be accessed from the internet, not from any S3 gateway nor interface endpoints.

If you want to access your s3 website from a VPC, it must have internet gateway and NAT if you are doing that from a private subnet.